# Change of basis isomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis, vector-space-isomorphism

So I am reading the following article on wikipedia:

[image]

My confusion stems from line 5 under the "Change of Basis" heading. They propose that $\phi_2^{-1}$$\phi_1$ is a change of coordinates automorphism.

However, $\phi_1$ is an isomorphism and takes the standard basis $e_i$ and changes it to the basis $\alpha_i$ and then $\phi_2^{-1}$ takes the standard basis $e_i$ and changes it to the basis $\alpha_i'$. So it's inverse suggests it would take coordinates in the $\alpha_i'$ basis and convert it back to the canonical basis. Therefore, when applied in that order I am confused that it does the necessary transformation given that we first convert to $\alpha_i$ and then the application of $\phi_2^{-1}$ seems redundant as it is being fed the wrong basis.

I hope that makes sense. If someone could explain this to me I would be very grateful.

Thanks,

Comment: I *strongly* recommend linking to the article - [particularly to this section of the article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_basis#The_matrix_of_a_linear_transformation) instead of posting a picture of it. It is much more readable, and people can examine the context.

Comment: Sorry Paul, was not aware previously. Next time I will

Comment: Actually, as I think about it, it probably is better to have a permanent record here, since wikipedia is subject to change. This way future readers will be able to see what you are talking about even if someone completely rewrites the article. But you should also include a link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ are the maps from $\Bbb R^n \to V$ defined by $$\phi_1(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i\alpha_i\\\phi_2(y_1, \ldots, y_n) = \sum_{i=1}^n y_i\beta_i$$
These are called coordinate isomorphisms because each imposes a coordinate system on $V$. Every vector $v \in V$ is identified by $\phi_1$ with a unique set of coordinates $(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ such that $v = \sum_i x_i\alpha_i$, and similarly, $\phi_2$ identifies the same vector $v$ with a different set of coordinates $(y_1, \ldots, y_n)$.

So I can locate $v$ using its $\phi_1$ coordinates, or I can locate it using its $\phi_2$ coordinates. But what if I want to compare these two coordinate systems? How are they related to each other? That is what the change of basis matrix is about:

We have $\phi_1(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = v$ and $\phi_2(y_1, \ldots, y_n) = v$, or since these are invertible, $$(y_1, \ldots, y_n) = \phi_2^{-1}(v) = \phi_2^{-1}(\phi_1(x_1, \ldots, x_n))$$

So $\phi_2^{-1}\circ\phi_1$ carries the $\phi_1$ coordinates of $v$ to the $\phi_2$ coordinates of $v$. Since both $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ are linear, this is a linear transformation from $\Bbb R^n$ to itself. a.k.a, an $n\times n$ matrix. The matrix tells you how to convert $\phi_1$ coordinates into $\phi_2$ coordinates.

For example, Let $V = \{f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R : t\mapsto at + b \mid a,b \in \Bbb R\}$ be the space of all affine functions on $\Bbb R$. A couple of bases for $V$ are $$\{\alpha_1 : t \mapsto 2t+1, \alpha_2 : t \mapsto t+2\}\\\{\beta_1 : t \mapsto -t, \alpha_2 : t \mapsto t-1\}$$
Then $$\phi_1(x_1, x_2) = \bigg(t\mapsto (2x_1 + x_2)t + (x_1 + 2x_2)\bigg)\\\phi_2(y_1, y_2) = \bigg(t \mapsto (y_2 - y_1)t - y_2\bigg)$$
It is easy to calculate $\phi_2^{-1}(t \mapsto at + b) = (-a-b,-b)$, so
$$\phi_2^{-1}\circ\phi_1 = \begin{bmatrix}-3&&-3\\-2&&-1\end{bmatrix}$$

So if I know that some $v \in V$ is given in $\alpha$ coordinates by $v = -2\alpha_1 + 3\alpha_2$, to find its expression in $\beta$ coordinates, I can just apply the change of basis matrix to calculate it directly:
$$\begin{bmatrix}-3&&-3\\-2&&-1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}-2\\3\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}-3\\1\end{bmatrix}$$ So $$v = -3\beta_1 + \beta_2$$

Comment: Could you please expand on what you did from the line beginning "It is easy to calculate...".. I understand thematric multiplication at the end but am not sure what you did on this line to get the transformaiton matrix. Are you able to write it out explicitly please?

Comment: You need to find $y_1, y_2$ such that $\phi_2(y_1, y_2) = \bigg(t \mapsto at + b\bigg)$. That means $$y_2 - y_1 = a\\-y_2 = b$$ which is easily solved to get $y_1 = -a-b, y_2 = -b$.

Comment: The next step is just to combine it with $\phi_1$, so $$(x_1, x_2) \to (2x_1+x_2)t + (x_1 + 2x_2) \to \big(-(2x_1+x_2) - (x_1 +2x_2), - (x_1 +2x_2)\big)\\(x_1, x_2) \to (-3x_1 -3x_2, -2x_1 - x_2)$$ which is the action of that transformation matrix.